# how to query list of data in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have List = {1,2}, I want to retrieve data of child ("deals/{1,2})

```
 fun deal_detail(deal: List<Deals>): Flowable<List<Deal_detail>> =
        observeValueEvent(ref1.child("deals")).map { snapshot ->
            snapshot.children.mapNotNull { child ->
                var name = child.child("$deal/dealable/keyword").getValue().toString()
                Deal_detail(name)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please add your database structure to see it more clearly.

Answer (score -1):

i solve the problem use map for list data.....
ref: https://medium.com/@justintulk/how-to-query-arrays-of-data-in-firebase-aa28a90181ba

```
 fun deal_detail(deal: List<Deals>): Flowable<Deal_detail> =
        observeValueEvent(ref1.child("deals")).map {
            snapshot->
                var deal1 = deal.map { id ->
                    snapshot.child(id.name.toString()).child("/dealable/keyword").getValue().toString()
                   }
            var image=deal.map { id->
                snapshot.child(id.name.toString()).child("dealable/image").getValue().toString()
            }

                Deal_detail(deal1,image)
        }
```